# syntax error inserting values using store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

```
create procedure sp_FldBkgData
(
    IN awb int,
    IN origin varchar(2),
    IN dist varchar(2),
    IN courier int,
    IN pdate varchar(10),
    IN acc int,
    IN service varchar(1),
    IN agent1 varchar(5),
    IN agent2 varchar(5),
    IN bkgtime int,
    IN sname varchar(45),
    IN sadd1 varchar(45),
    IN sadd2 varchar(45),
    IN sadd3 varchar(45),
    IN scity varchar(45),
    IN sstate varchar(25),
    IN spostal int,
    IN scountry varchar(8),
    IN sph varchar(11),
    IN sfax varchar(25),
    IN smail varchar(45),
    IN sref varchar(45),
    IN carrier varchar(45),
    IN ccompany varchar(45),
    IN cname varchar(45),
    IN cadd1 varchar(45),
    IN cadd2 varchar(45),
    IN cadd3 varchar(45),
    IN ccity varchar(25),
    IN cstate varchar(15),
    IN ccountry varchar(45),
    IN cgateway varchar(3),
    IN cph varchar(25),
    IN goods varchar(45),
    IN paymode varchar(7),
    IN curr varchar(3),
    IN val int,
    IN pcs int,
    IN weight double,
    IN handling varchar(1),
    IN insurrance varchar(3),
    IN fac int,
    IN gst int
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO cms_module_fieldbooking (Awb) VALUES (awb);
END
```

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: Did you intend to ask a question? Or were just giving a status report on your current development efforts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a procedure in the MySQL Workbench Query Editor, you need to specify a delimiter other than the semicolon.

For example:

```
  DELIMITER $$

  CREATE PROCEDURE foo() 
  BEGIN
     SELECT 'foo';
  END$$

  DELIMITER ;
```

As an alternative, MySQL Workbench also has a "routine" editor that automatically handles the delimiter for you. (In the schema list on the left, right click on Procedures, and select "Create Procedure".  When you click Apply, you'll see the actual script, that includes the DELIMITER statements.